# alternate element missing in a bootstrap form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple bootstrap form that has 2 select elements one below the other. 
But just 1 select shows up.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputType" placeholder="Type">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1" class="col-md-2 control-label">sel1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" placeholder="Type">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel2" class="col-md-2 control-label">sel2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="sel2" placeholder="Type">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/0brx0jx0/ that demonstrates this.

any pointers?

Comment: You want dropdown elements?

Comment: yes, several of them one, below the other. The form seems to hide the alternate ones. Try adding one more form-group in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't close the select tag. Try following.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputType" class="col-md-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputType" placeholder="Type">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1" class="col-md-2 control-label">sel1</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="sel1" placeholder="Type">
                <option>opt1</option>
                <option>opt2</option>
                <option>opt3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel2" class="col-md-2 control-label">sel2</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" id="sel2" placeholder="Type">
                <option>opt1</option>
                <option>opt2</option>
                <option>opt3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. this fragment was being used with in a angular js app and it uses attributes to do the binding. so i just closed the select with a /> and it worked for the first element. but broke others. needs an explicit </select> closeout.
completely forgot the basics :)
Thanks Ashim